# Issue Installing eclim for Eclipse(version check failed) macOS

Tags: java, eclipse, eclim

I am having issues trying to install eclim for macOS 10.11.6.

Following instructions [here](http://eclim.org/install.html), I get to the "validating requirements" screen. However, it is glitched so I cant see the error but the error is next to the "checking eclipse version".

If I continue, I can select my features and get the error

```
jar:file:/users/myname/Downloads/eclim_2.6.0.jar/installer.xml:321: Replace: source file /Users/myname/eclipse/java-neon/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclim_2.60/bin/eclimd doesn't exist
```

I am sure I am just doing something wrong, but anyone have any help? I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue for this on the [Eclim github](https://github.com/ervandew/eclim/issues/479) page with the workaround that you have to install eclipse from the [*.tar.gz](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/?osType=macosx&release=undefined) and not from the installer app.

Answer (score 0):

From [Eric Van Dewoestine](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/eclim-user/vM8pyXP4WXI/6k1kNlO3AQAJ)

> The eclim gui installer does not support the eclipse file layout 
>   created by the eclipse gui installer. If you use one of the .tar.gz 
>   eclipse distributions instead, that should resolve the problem.

I've the same issue in Debian Jessie.